# Security of OKHttp Cached Responses

Tags: android, okhttp

How secure and accessible are the cached responses from Okhttp?

I know that we can define a file to cache our items in, but I was wondering if there was a file that would provide optimal security for caching API-Keys, or a way to increase the security for OkHttp.

If not, is there a more secure way to cache API-Keys between Application re-starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite Secure, unless you control the device.  Assuming your cache looks like

```
return OkHttpClient.Builder()
    // Around 4¢ worth of storage in 2020
    .cache(Cache(File(applicationContext.cacheDir, "api_cache"), 50 * 1024 * 1024))
    .build()
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

> Internal storage directories: These directories include both a
> dedicated location for storing persistent files, and another location
> for storing cache data. The system prevents other apps from accessing
> these locations, and on Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, these
> locations are encrypted. These characteristics make these locations a
> good place to store sensitive data that only your app itself can
> access.

Also read https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: But still we can access on root device.

Comment: OkHttp 5, currently Alpha will allow you to provide your own Cache FileSystem.

Comment: oh, that's a nice feature.